# nested list based on type column in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, list

I have an angularjs [sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/tpt8g8xx/) where it contains a sample array

```
 $scope.myarr = [
{id: 1, name: 'foo',type: 1},
{id: 2,name: 'bar',type: 1},
{id: 3,name: 'quad',type: 2},
{id: 4,name: 'cab',type: 2},
{id: 5,name: 'baz',type: 2},
{id: 6,name: 'cad',type: 3}
];
```

Myself trying to create a list using `ng-repeat` and it can be done as

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in myarr">
<li>{{x.id}}. {{x.name}} - Type {{x.type}}</li>
</ul>
```

But actually what is wanted is a nested list based on `x.type` column as,

1. Type 1

   - 1. foo
   - 2. bar
2. Type 2

   - 3. quad
   - 4. cab
   - 5. baz
3. Type 3

   - 6. cad

How can it be done using angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of a inner `ng-repeat` and `filter` / `unique`

**AngularJS doesn't include a unique filter by default. You can use the one from angular-filter. Just include the JavaScript**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

**and include the dependeny in your app:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
```

More information on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<div id="app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="x in myarr | unique:'type'">
      <li>{{x.id}}. {{x.name}} - Type {{x.type}}</li>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="y in myarr | filter:type=x.id"> 
          {{y.name}}
        </li>   
      </ul>
  </ul>
</div>

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.myarr = [
    {id: 1, name: 'foo',type: 1},
    {id: 2,name: 'bar',type: 1},
    {id: 3,name: 'quad',type: 2},
    {id: 4,name: 'cab',type: 2},
    {id: 5,name: 'baz',type: 2},
    {id: 6,name: 'cad',type: 3}
  ];
});
```

Will give a result of :

```
Type 1
    1. foo
    2. bar
Type 2
    3. quad
    4. cab
    5. baz
Type 3
    6. cad
```

**See updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/tpt8g8xx/4/)**

Comment: I've re-forked - does this link work ? https://jsfiddle.net/2y460yvp/  or do you mean something else with not working?

Comment: Got it worked: https://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/tpt8g8xx/4/. Need to include external angular filter file to work `unique` Thanks :)

Comment: Great, just updated my answer while you found it yourself :)